# Wordpress custom fields not saved in database

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I've been running a WordPress site for over a year now and never had a problem with it until yesterday. I'm using a custom field to store the url to a preview image for every post. I simply add it using the standard Custom Fields form in the Edit Post screen. Before when I'd save the post as a draft or if I immediately published it the custom field would be saved. But now all of a sudden no matter how I save the post (save as draft, publish or auto-save) the custom field isn't being stored in the database. I did confirm this by checking the wp_postmeta table.

I already reinstalled Wordpress, but it doesn't change a thing. I also went through other similar posts about this subject, but none of the solutions work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using WP's standard "enter custom fields" field?

Comment: Did it really happened "from nothing", or did you updated/installed something previously? [Do a full troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-34-master-list).

Comment: @Pekka yes just the standard custom field form

Comment: @brasofilo As far as I know it did happen from nothing. No new plugins installed or updated.

Comment: What about the troubleshooting?

Comment: I'll try that when I'm back home and I'll post the outcome of that. Cheers.

Comment: Okay so I've tried disabling every single plugin one by one and retrying to save the custom field everytime. No luck. Also optimized the database, but also no change. Is there a way to debug this? Can I make WordPress log everything it does for instance, so I can actually target the problem more specifically? Any other ideas are welcome too, really pulling my hair out over this one. :(

Comment: Okay this just got stranger. The name of the custom field I'm trying to use is 'paddimage'. As a test I now tried to add a custom field with a different name, such as 'paddima' and that does get saved to the database. Also other custom fields with different names work, except for that one specific name. I already searched the whole code for this name, but it only appears in the theme folder nowhere in the admin area or functions where I would expect this to go bad. Any ideas based on this new information?

Answer (score 0):

So after digging deeper, I figured out the custom field was dependent on another field. Still not sure why it wouldn't store the custom field in the database even though the other field wasn't filled out first. But it works anyway when I do it that way. WordPress works in mysterious ways sometimes.